# What is the best way to connect a MacBook Pro to a Samsung TV set?

Tags: macbook-pro, video, television, video-adapter

I would like to connect my MacBook Pro, which has <strike>Mini-DVI</strike> DisplayPort and FireWire ports (I have DisplayPort to DVI converter as well).

What is the best way to connect it to a Samsung TV, which has the ports shown below?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most expensive but most likely the best way would be an AppleTV plus something like airserver.

Answer (score 2):

Well it really depends on WHICH MacBook Pro you have as there are a number of output options available.

If you have a fairly recent one I would get the mini display port to HDMI adapter available from Apple (or Amazon, or whoever) and an HDMI cable and use that. It also has the benefit of carrying audio as well so you don't need a separate audio cable.

I use this exact setup with my Mac Mini to play videos I get from the iTunes store on my living room TV set. Works a treat!

Comment: HDMI might be ABLE to transmit audio, but the Mini-Display port doesn't, so unless you have a native HDMI port, audio will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Mini-DVI does not carry audio, so a Mini-DVI to HDMI cable won't carry audio. However, it is by far superior to VGA or component connections.

For the audio, you can use a 3.5mm male to male cable, and connect to the `PC/DVI AUDIO IN` jack. You can also use a 3.5mm cable to red and white components like the one below. They're of equal quality, so it comes down to what you can find.

[image]

The most favourable option for audio however, depends not on your TV but on your audio system. I see you have an optical audio out cable leading out of your TV, which leads me to assume you have an audio system which accepts at least one optical audio input. Using a toshlink cable with a toshlink to minitoshlink adapter (which are typically sold together) with the audio connection will ensure the highest quality audio (even support surround sound).

[image]

Comment: A Mac actually has a Thunderbolt port and a Thunderbolt to HDMI adapter would carry both audio and video right?

Comment: Depends on which MacBook you have, the older ones have a mini-display port, but yes. A thunderbolt port **looks** the same as a mini display port so the same adapter suffices.

Comment: He mentioned that his mac has mini dvi, which isnt present on any models with thunderbolt (afaik). Thunderbolt is a combination of PCIe and minidisplay port. The regular adapters to HDMI use the mini-display port portion of the protocol, which does not carry audio